# error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function C++

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ by book and was trying to test simple coding for a looped game combat.  A switch inside a while loop.

```
damage = greatsword[0] + player[1] - enemy[2]; endl;
```

> error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function|

I have this error in 4 different code lines and in each one it has 'damage' so I assume its some problem with that.  I have damage declared as an int and set to 0 before trying to change it to the attack value.  I can provide more of the code if needed.  I also tried changing the name from x to dmg to see if that was the problem

Comment: Please post the whole code not only that line. 
Also why do you have an endl; at the end of that line?

Comment: Don't edit the question to say it was resolved. **Accept** an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing `endl;` which you probably did not mean to include. [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function which is used when printing to an output stream; usually you'll see `cout << ... << endl;`, but otherwise it should not be used.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation.  That fixed it and i guess I can drop using endl a lot more

Answer (score 0):

`std::endl`, as used as a stream manipulator, is actually a function.

You probably achieve a similar or related error message by doing this

```
 void f();   // don't need to define f()

 int main()
 {
      f;    //   should be f() to call the function
 }
```

So remove the statement `endl;`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, also thanks for the explanation.